# Why Am I Showing Different Markets for the Same Stock on Different Sites

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-markets, yahoo-finance

I have recently been looking at some penny stocks, and I've noticed that for some I see the OTC market that is listed as different between various sites and I'm not sure why? Which should I trust?

Example

Ticker: BLPG

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BLPG/?p=BLPG shows OTC BB
http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/BLPG/quote shows OTC Pink

Comment: They are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OTCBB no longer functions as a market, but is simply a quotation system (bulletin board) serving the other OTC markets.

Each of the OTC markets has different listing requirements. OTC Pink is the "loosest" of the OTC markets, having absolutely no standards or reporting requirements.  The other OTC markets are OTCQB and OTCQX, each of which have standards and reporting requirements.

In this case, yahoo is quoting the OTCBB quotation system, which for BLPG is simply the OTC pink quotes since BLPG only lists on the pink sheets.  So, in effect, you are seeing the same quote provided by two different quote systems.

Comment: That makes sense. This is all new to me. I did notice that otcmarkets.com only lists OTCQX, OTCQB, and OTCPink. I suppose then when I see stocks showing they were quoted from OTCBB, I should classify them as actually being listed on the OTCPink exchange? Also, another stock, CNAB, shows OTC BB on Yahoo! Finance but OTC QB on OTC Markets, I assume this is the same situation where it is actually listed and traded on the OTC QB exchange?